# Image click image set on imageview but second time image click then force close

Tags: android, image, android-activity, android-tabhost

**FATAL EXCEPTION:**

```
    android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: 
    Unable to add window -- token 
android.app.LocalActivityManager$LocalActivityRecord@4053bfd8 is not valid; is your
activity running?
    at android.view.ViewRoot.setView(ViewRoot.java:527)
    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:177)
    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)    
    at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:424)
    at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
    10-30 17:00:28.060: E/AndroidRuntime(1921): 
    at com.kwuit.tuitiontracker.students.AddNewStudent$2.onClick(AddNewStudent.java:144)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Hear Code This Code is Image Click on one time then image is Gallery to fatch Perfecet diplay image on Image view But second time image click then force close please help

```
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
// setContentView(R.layout.add_new_student_layout);
group = this;
View contentView = LayoutInflater.from(getParent()).inflate(
        R.layout.add_new_student_layout, null);
setContentView(contentView);

try {
    edtStudentId = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_student_id);
    edtStudentJoiningDate = (EditText) 

                findViewById(R.id.edit_jonining_date);
    edtStudentName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_name);
    edtStudentAddress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_address);
    edtStudentTelephone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_telephone);
    btnSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_save);
    btnCancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_cancel);
    imgPhoto = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_student_photo);

    /**
     * create DatabaseHandler object
     */
    db = new DataBaseHandler(this);
    /**
     * Reading and getting all records from database
     */
    List<Contact> contacts = db.getAllContacts();
    for (Contact cn : contacts) {
        String log = "ID:" + cn.getID() + " Name: " + cn.getName()
                + " ,Image: " + cn.getImage();

        // Writing Contacts to log
        Log.d("Result: ", log);
        // add contacts data in arrayList
        imageArry.add(cn);

    }

    /**
     * Set Data base Item into listview
     */
    /*
     * imageAdapter = new ContactImageAdapter(this,
     * R.layout.screen_list, imageArry);
     * dataList.setAdapter(imageAdapter);
     */
    /**
     * go to next activity for detail image
     */

    for (int i = 0; i < imageArry.size(); i++) {

        Contact picture = imageArry.get(i);
        // convert byte to bitmap take from contact class

        byte[] outImage = picture._image;
        ByteArrayInputStream imageStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(
                outImage);
        theImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
        imgPhoto.setImageBitmap(theImage);
    }

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    /**
     * open dialog for choose camera/gallery
     */

    final String[] option = new String[] { "Take from Camera",
            "Select from Gallery" };
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, option);

    builder.setTitle("Select Option");
    builder.setAdapter(adapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.e("Selected Item", String.valueOf(which));
            if (which == 0) {
                callCamera();
            }
            if (which == 1) {
                callGallery();
            }

        }
    });
    final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();

    imgPhoto.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog.show();

            imageArry = null;
            theImage = null;
        }
    });

    btnSave.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                addStudedntInDatabase();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    btnCancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
        }
    });
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

}

Comment: Paste the code you are using

Comment: The problem seems to be in AddNewStudent class. Post its code